How to decode VARILRAW to itab
I have an older version of ABAP and would benefit greatly for my tasks from a program that retrieves variant values from canceled tasks with a specific name, etc. I did a trace of transaction SM37 and found out that using tables V_OP, TBTCP and VARI it is possible to get the variant value I am interested in with data type VARILRAW(LRAW) which is in the CLUSTD field of table VARI. Internet search did not bring me to the right path, I tried different ways, but I could not get the data in itab. So the question is, is it possible to do this and if so, what methods or FM`s should I use?
Ive tried
IMPORT lt_var FROM DATA BUFFER lv_xstring
where
lt var TYPE TABLE OF rsparams
and lv_xstring is converted to xstring CLUSTD value from VARI table. Thats not get it.

UPD: found the solution, all you have to get from Db tables is report name and variant name. After that, you can use FM RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS. That`s it, problem solved.
